# Zero width word joiner and CSS generated content

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I want to disallow line breaks in some places in a web page (eg. it's really ugly when the browser breaks the text "100 km/h" on two lines - in this question I'm concerned about breaking near the "/"). I tried this approach and it works

```
x&zwj;/&zwj;y <!-- x/y on one line -->
```

The entity `&zwj;` is a zero-width word joiner, similar to `&nbsp;`, but without space.

However, I am concerned about a slightly more complex example:

```
x&zwj;/<span class="someclass"></span>
```

with style:

```
.someclass { content: "y"; }
```

This seems to work in Firefox (no linebreaks between normal and generated content), but in Opera, it fails. Should this work according to the standards?

Answer (score 2):

Set `white-space: nowrap;` as seen here: [webdesignerwall.com](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-simple-but-useful-css-properties)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Moving content into CSS is not reasonable in this case. Also, zero-width joiner and non-joiner have nothing to do with linebreaks, but are intended to alter ligature rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting the br element to display none worked for me on Chrome. I'm not sure about FF, IE, and the like, but it shouldn't be too hard to check!

```
.someclass br { display: none; }
```

Comment: Opera 10.63 and Safari 5.0.3 also pass the test. I'd say this is a pretty well supported method for preventing line breaks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me either on Opera 11 and Seamonkey 2.0.6. Shouldn't this work only on breaks specifically inserted with the `<br>` element?

Comment: That's strange. I just updated Opera to version 11 and it still worked. What are you running? Yea, it should, because not including the pre tag, any line breaks in the HTML are not interpreted as line breaks on the page. What other kinds of breaks are you referring to?

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I am concerned about line breaks created by the browser during text flow layout. Ie. your comment displays as 3 lines here, and I'm interested about the line breaks between them. The `&zwj;` should be akin to `&nbsp;` except there's no space.